# jQuery htmlentities output result without enclosing "" and output result in a separate div

Tags: php, jquery, html-entities

I have this jQuery code:

```
var session;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('processupload.php', function (data) {
    session = data;
});
```

I have this PHP code:

```
print json_encode($_SESSION['StoreImageCode'] =htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg>" />'));
```

This outputs (for example)
`"<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg>"`
as source code.

The problem is that I want to output the value without it being enclosed in `""` tags. The other problem is I don't know how to use that jQuery code to output in a separate div such as `#output`. Please can someone help me with this!

Comment: this `<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg>" ` should read as `<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg">` try that, could be the problem. Double quote was outside the `src` - let me know Harry.

Answer (score 0):

This `<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg>"` should read as `<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg">`

Try that, could be the problem.

Double quote was outside the `src`

**Change:**

```
print json_encode($_SESSION['StoreImageCode'] =htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg>" />'));
```

**to:**

```
print json_encode($_SESSION['StoreImageCode'] =htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg"> />'));
```